# Proving f(n) is O(2^n)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-science, complexity-theory, big-o

I understand how to use the definition of Big-O to prove an f(n) is O(n) or O(n^2) but I get lost with O(2^n) can you help prove 2^n +n^3 + 30 is O(2^n) pls? Bsc AI Yr1 Love it all but complexity is kickin my ass!

Comment: Can you solve limits? Then prove that |2^n|/|2^n + n^3 + 30| converges, and you're done.

Comment: It doesn't even have to converge. As long as it's bounded.

Comment: Can you just use 3^n as the upperbound?

Comment: We have to use the c and n0 method

Comment: Actually, you need to look at |2^n + n^3 + 30|/|2^n|.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to solve the problem for you, because it sounds like homework.  But I will solve one you already know how to solve, and then try to convince you that this problem is no different.

So.  Recall what it is we're doing when we're trying to prove that some function, call it f(n), belongs to Big-Oh of some other function, call it g(n).  We're trying to prove that *up to some constant factor* and *as n gets large*, f(n) is never worse than g(n).  We do that by picking two numbers, c and n<sub>0</sub>.  The first, c, is that "constant factor" I mentioned before.  We're going to relate f(n) to g(n) as follows:

f(n) ≤ c g(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

The thing is, c and n0 are not unique.  Often, you can pick one almost arbitrarily, and figure out the value for the other with simple algebra.  So let's try this with

f(n) = n² + 5n + 10

g(n) = n²

First we set the relation up according to our constant factor, c:

n² + 5n + 10 ≤ c n²

Now we want to get c by itself, related to some other function of n, so just divide the n² out of both sides:

1 + 5/n + 10/n² ≤ c

We want to know what value of n (which we call n<sub>0</sub>) makes that true for all larger values of n.  Well, we can either pick a c and solve for n, or pick an n<sub>0</sub> and solve for c.  Doesn't really matter, but let's pick n<sub>0</sub> = 1, just plug that in everywhere we see n, and see what happens:

1 + 5/1 + 10/1 = 1 + 5 + 10 = 16 ≤ c

And that's our answer:  If we pick c as 16, then whenever n is larger than 1 (i.e., n<sub>0</sub> = 1) then f(n) will be smaller than g(n).

Now, can you do that with the problem you're trying to solve?  Well... why not?  We have two functions, f(n) and g(n).  We're trying to prove exactly the same relationship as in the problems you know how to solve.  All that's changed is the type of functions, from polynomials in n, to exponentials in n (and one that's mixed.)  But does that matter?  Well, the algebra will look a little different, but so what?  It's algebra.

Comment: This is really helpful thank you so much (apologies for delay as forgot to set email notifications - only just seen)

Answer (score 1):

[Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) defines the behavior of a function as it approaches some value. Often, we say infinity, but generally "an arbitrarily large number" is sufficient.

Thus, you're in the world of mathematical limits; [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) will be helpful here, but let's consider your case. To show that:

```
O(2^n +n^3 + 30) == O(2^n)
```

we need to show that, as `n` tends to a large number, `2^n +n^3 + 30` tends towards `2^n`. By inspection, you can see that, when `n` is 10, `n^3` is 1000, so already much larger than 30 (and growing, as `n` grows). At this point, `2^n` is 1024, so it's of the same order as `n^3`, but also getting larger. Once `n` is 100, `n^3` is 1 million, `2^n` is 5 times this number (`1 x 10^30`)... so clearly that first terms is outstripping the others and `n` is not what we'd call "arbitrarily large"

So, by inspection, we know that

```
O(2^n +n^3 + 30) == O(2^n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the tools you can use. At first sight, it is pretty obvious, so you probably have to go deeper into the proof.

Basically, n^3 is ridiculously small compared to 2^n so n^3 ~ o(2^n).

Same for a constant 30.

So

`2^n + n^3 + 30 ~ 2^n + o(2^n) ~ O(2^n)` by definition.

If it is not enough as a proof, you can prove that

`limit n^3/2^n (when n-> infinity) = 0`

Comment: We have to actually prove it by definition

Comment: What do you mean by definition ? I guess you are supposed to use some theorems you have in your toolbox, right ?

Comment: eg prove 2n^2 + 5 is O(n^2) for n>=1

Answer (score 0):

Prove that `n^3 < 2^n for some n > n0` (by induction or look at some typical math exercises and reference it. You do not have to find the smallest n0, just any n0)

Then show with this result that `|2^n + n^3 + 30| <= |2^n +2^n + 2^n|` and find a nicely looking c between 2 and 4 to show that the last term is smaller than `c*|2^n|`.

After all this, write everything together and you should have something like `|2^n +n^3 + 30| <= ... <= c*|2^n| for n > <n0> and c=<value>` (`<n0>` and `<value>` should be some numbers after you are finished). Which is the definition.